# How to align text and Picker in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

How do we align a Text to be next to an Input in React Native? In the image below the Text is in the top left but the Picker seems to have padding or margin applied. I tried other solutions with flex but also [ran into this problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6110)

[image: incorrect alignment of text and picker]

Answer (score 3):

This works for me -

```
  <View style={styles.Container}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flex:.5}}>
        <Text>Placeholder</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:.5}}>
        <Picker>
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java"/>
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js"/>
        </Picker>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

You can change the flex values according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there were a couple of things I was missing? If I remove the `alignItems: 'center'` then it goes back to the incorrect layout I had. If I remove the `style={{flex:.5}}` from the `View`'s for the `Text` and `Picker` I get `Invalid layout`. So I'm guessing both of these are essential. Do you know of any good resources for learning this properly?

Comment: This worked. Setting `flex:.5` is key. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with the picker. Give equal flex for both text and picker(eg: parent have flex: 1 and give flex: 0.5 to both text and picker ). Better to give height and width to the picker according to your screen size. I think you didn't give **flexDirection**(row) to that the parent View. And also give height and width for items to the picker.

Sample code for giving style to picker:

```
    <Picker
        style={styles.picker}
        mode="dropdown"
        itemStyle={styles.itemStyle}>
            <Item label="1 Hr" value="1" />
            <Item label="4 Hrs" value="4" />
            <Item label="8 Hrs" value="8" />
            <Item label="16 Hrs" value="16" />
            <Item label="24 Hrs" value="24" />
    </Picker>
```

Styles:

```
itemStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    height: 75,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
picker: {
    width: 100
  },
```

Its working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Your answer and the one supplied by vinayr were both correct in that I needed to give a flex to both the `Text` and `Picker`, however, I also need use `alignItems: 'center'` on the parent `View` otherwise it doesn't align properly as per my original screenshot. Does it work fine for you without `alignItems: 'center'`?

Comment: It doesn't work properly without giving alignItems: 'center'

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.Container}>
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{flex:.5}}>
    <Text>Placeholder</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex:.5}}>
    <Picker itemStyle={{textAlign:"left"}}>
      <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java"/>
      <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js"/>
    </Picker>
  </View>
</View>
```

This worked for me.