# How to change text align and font color in react native picker for android and ios both

Tags: react-native, picker

This is my code

```
<Picker
       mode="dropdown"
       selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
       itemStyle={{textAlign:'center',color:'#ff0000'}}
       onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerValueHolder: itemValue})} >
        <Picker.Item color='#ff00000' label="React Native" value="React Native"  />
        <Picker.Item label="Java" value="Java" />
        <Picker.Item label="Html" value="Html" />
        <Picker.Item label="Php" value="Php" />
        <Picker.Item label="C++" value="C++" />
        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="JavaScript" />
      </Picker>
```

I used item style but its not working and important thing is didn't want to fix height or width. The available solution have fix width.

[How to align text and Picker in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850919/how-to-align-text-and-picker-in-react-native)

I tried this above link but in this solution i found fix width but i didn't want to fix width solution.

[image: This my output where i want to centralize the text]

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850919/how-to-align-text-and-picker-in-react-native

Comment: i already mentioned above that i tried this but its not working